# Python database insert

Tags: python, pyodbc

I've been trying to parse a text file (opened with parameter encoding='utf8') and insert extracted values into an mdb database using pyodbc module.
I have tried the code below:

```
for line in fp:
    tokens = line.split('\t')
    tokens[4] = tokens[4][:len(tokens[4])-1] #to avoid the \n
    tokens[1] = tokens[1][1:] #to remove the 'u' from the beginning of utf8 characters like u'\u0622'
    content = conn.execute("INSERT INTO Entries (PForm, WForm, Code, Freq, Pattern) VALUES ("+tokens[0]+","+tokens[1]+","+tokens[2]+","+tokens[3]+","+tokens[4]+")")
    conn.commit()
```

and received the following error:
Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 4. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

P.S. the first line of my file is: آ    'A  Ab  1   S

And the other lines are of the same format.

Your comments will be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you put a raw line from the text file and the "Entries" schema?

Comment: The text file contains many lines, each line contains five tokens separated by a tab. The three first lines are like:
 آ 'A Ab 1 S\n

برآ barA V1 5000 WS\n

بوآ bo'A N1 1 WS\n

Comment: and the table "Entries" has exactly five columns as indicated in the 5th line of my code

Comment: can you print tokens before the execute and post here the output?

Comment: [u'\u0622', u'A', u'Ab', u'1', u'S']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't put quotes around the strings which you want to insert. Assuming the "Freq" row is of type INTEGER:

```
stmt = """
INSERT INTO Entries (PForm, WForm, Code, Freq, Pattern)
    VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', %s, '%s')
"""

params = tuple(t for t in tokens)

conn.execute(stmt % params)
```

But anyway, you shouldn't be formatting an `INSERT` statement like this. Doesn't the library you're using provide a facility to parameterize statements ? Something like this:

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (foo, bar, baz))
```