# Validating Excel cell value and inserting into SQL error HY000 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to validating the excel data if it is > 12 chr length then i need to insert in a table (sql) with python code

I have tried with this  code and i am getting the below error

'The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Value in excel already with closed brackets like ('12ewrr334dgdgskngk')

and i ran the query in SSMS and it is working fine 
INSERT INTO  #finalresultset1 ( VIN )  Values  ('12ewrr334dgdgskngk')

```
import xlrd 
import pyodbc



book = xlrd.open_workbook(r'excelpath')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name(r'Sheet')


cnxn = pyodbc.connect('database connection')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

query = """ INSERT INTO  #finalresultset1 ( VIN )  Values   """


VINSheet = sheet.ncols
for row in range(0,sheet.nrows):
    for col in range(0,VINSheet):
        cell_VIN = sheet.cell(row,col)
        if len(cell_VIN.value) >= 12:
           cursor.execute(query, cell_VIN.value)

        else:
            print('VIN Length must be greater than 17')
```

---

> Tried `cursor.execute(query, (cell_VIN.value, ))`
>   This time i got the different error
>
> ```
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', 
> "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
> Invalid object name '#finalresultset1'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); 
> [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
> Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
> ```
>
> and I verified the temp table it is exist in my DB

---

> EDIT
>
> ```
> cursor.execute(" INSERT INTO #finalresultset1 ( product ) Values (?) ", 
>                  cell_VIN.value)
> ```

Comment: It's unlikely that `cell_VIN.value` are a tuple `('12ewrr334dgdgskngk')`.

Comment: I removed the close brackets and tried ,getting the same error

Comment: Try `cursor.execute(query, (cell_VIN.value, ))`

Comment: This time i got the different error   pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#finalresultset1'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
and I verified the temp table it is exist in my DB

Comment: Change your `cursor.execute(...`, like in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16458514/7414759)

Comment: The parameters may be passed **as a sequence** or **as individual values**. use either `... Values (?) ", (cell_VIN.value, ))` **or**  without *Values* `... ?", cell_VIN.value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
query = """ INSERT INTO  #finalresultset1 ( VIN )  Values (?)"""
```

(Add the `(?)` after `values`)

Comment: still getting first error pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: @Rahul: Edit your Question and show your current `query` and `.execute(...`. Read [pyodbc/wiki/Cursor](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor)

Comment: import xlrd 
import pyodbc



book = xlrd.open_workbook(r'excel path')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name(r'Sheet')


cnxn = pyodbc.connect('connection string')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()



VINSheet = sheet.ncols
for row in range(0,sheet.nrows):
    for col in range(0,VINSheet):
        cell_VIN = sheet.cell(row,col)
        if len(cell_VIN.value) >= 12:
           # print(cell_VIN.value)

           
           cursor.execute(" INSERT INTO  #finalresultset1 ( product ) Values (?)  ", cell_VIN.value)

        else:
            print('VIN Length must be greater than 17')

Comment: which error?  the error about the parameter count?  or the error about the table not existing?

Answer (score 0):

> Invalid object name '#finalresultset1'

`#finalresultset1` is a [local temporary table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#temporary-tables) because its name begins with `#`. You are opening your connection and then trying to insert into that table without creating it first. That will never work because local temporary tables only exist for the current session, and your session (created by the `connect` call) has not created that table.